# Conversion from string to type Integer from datarow vb

Tags: vb.net

I have a error:

> ex    {"Conversion from string ""TTSequenceEnable"" to type 'Integer' is
> not valid."}  System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

how convert this value `rows(0).ItemArray("TTSequenceEnable")` to a int, I try differents things and have the same error

```
Function IsSequenceEnable() As Boolean
        Try
            Dim dao As New ACBDAO.Custom
            Dim ttdeaults As DataTable
            ttdeaults = dao.GetTTDefaults()
            Dim rows() As DataRow = ttdeaults.Select()

            If Int(rows(0).ItemArray("TTSequenceEnable")) = 1 Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler.EH.HandleException(ex, False)
        End Try

    End Function
```

Comment: What is value of rows(0).ItemArray("TTSequenceEnable")? Is it a number string?

Comment: is a smallint I recieve of this way.

Comment: You should turn `Option Strict On` in your project properties and also in the IDE options, so that it's `On` by default for all future projects. That would have told you that indexing an array with a `String` is invalid at design time, instead of letting it slip to run time in the hope that the `String` could be implicitly converted to an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using `ItemArray` there. As the name suggests, it is an array of all the items in the row. You don't index an array by name. It is the `Item` property you should be using:

```vb
rows(0).Item("TTSequenceEnable")
```

or, given that `Item` is always the default property, just index the `DataRow` directly:

```vb
rows(0)("TTSequenceEnable")
```

Comment: With this i have another error "{"Column 'TTSequenceEnable' does not belong to table tblTT_DEFAULTS."}"

Comment: That is a different issue. I have shown you the correct way to get a value from a `DataRow` by column name. It should be obvious that you can't get data from any row by the name of a column that doesn't exist. Either you are using the wrong name or you haven't populated the `DataTable` properly in the first place but, either way, that has nothing to do with the issue you were asking about here.